# GuzzleHttp Error with certain plugins in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugin

I am getting GuzzleHttp errors when activating or trying to access a couple plugins in conjunction wit CiviCRM. This seems to be with newer versions of CiviCRM (5.52 & higher). I thought initially it was related to the ScormCloud plugin but then it came up with the google analytics plugin. Below are the errors.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler() in /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/scormcloud/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php:61 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(42): GuzzleHttp\choose_handler() 
#1 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(65): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create() 
#2 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/scormcloud/vendor/rustici-software/scormcloud-api-v2-client-php/src/Api/CourseApi.php(77): GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct() 
#3 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/scormcloud/SCORMCloud_PHPLibrary/ScormEngineService2.php(63): RusticiSoftware\Cloud\V2\Api\CourseApi->__construct(NULL, Object(RusticiSoftware\Cloud\V2\Configuration), NULL) 
#4 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/scormcloud/scormcloudplugin.php(106): ScormEngineService->__construct('https://cloud.s...', 'YJC8NJPV9J', 'Rl in /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/scormcloud/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php on line 61


An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 61 of the file /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/googleanalytics/lib/analytics-admin/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler() in /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/googleanalytics/lib/analytics-admin/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(42): GuzzleHttp\choose_handler()
#1 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(65): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create()
#2 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(52): GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct()
#3 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(252): CRM_Extension_Browser->getGuzzleClient()
#4 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(196): CRM_Extension_Browser->grabRemoteJson()
#5 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(151): CRM_Extension_Browser->_discoverRemot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably using guzzle7. Civi will work with guzzle7 but ships with 6, so you need to manually go into the civicrm folder (the one that has e.g. a CRM folder, a Civi folder, a vendor folder, a composer.json and composer.lock file, etc) and type `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:'^7'`.

Comment: After that change we'd have to do composer update correct?

Comment: No it doesn't seem to need that. If you feel adventurous you can do composer update, or add -W to the require command, but then you might get some versions of packages that haven't been well-tested with civi (although it would probably be similar to the versions that get installed with drupal 8).

Comment: Running this command has corrected the error with the ScormCloud plugin which is the priority. I will test the other plugin over the weekend. Thanks for the info!!